# Replace nio.file.Path::of(String) for java 8

Tags: java

I am converting some code using java 11 to java 8. Consider the following code in java 11:

```
import nio.file.Path;

public void foo(List<String> fileNames) {
  List<Path> filePaths = fileNames.stream().
                         map(Path::of).
                         collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Since [nio.file.Path::of](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) is a method since java 11, I have to replace it with some code in java 8.
I tried `nio.file.Path.resolve`, however, the resolve method is not correct since it is not a static method.

So, how can i modify the code to fit java 8?

Comment: java.nio.file.Paths.get? But I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Paths::get` instead of `Path:of` in the `map` operation of your stream.